# Ruins of famous landmarks in Shannara

Tags: shannara, shannara-chronicles

In the previews for the show "The Chronicles of Shannara", they often show things like a moss covered Space Needle on it's side, and a large cargo ship.  When I last read the books, I don't remember reading much about things like that. Were there any examples of famous landmarks in the ruins in the Four Lands?

Edit: This can include any book in the series.

Comment: Ruins of what were obviously modern cities?  Yes, book 1 had some tucked away in some mountains with a big beastie crawling around.  Specific landmarks, I don't think so, and I haven't read the books recently enough to answer for sure.

Comment: If I recall correctly, wasn't the post-apocalyptic nature of the setting a secret until several books in?

Comment: I remember in the Sword of Shannara (the first book published) was that there was another time with modern technology, and they did explore a ruin with a (creeper?) beast in it, as mentioned by Radhil.

Comment: @SeanDuggan No, it was made explicit up front, and the different races described as mutant humans and post-apocalypse known.  It just wasn't relevant except as color detail, since it was long past, until later series (*Voyage of the Jerle Shannara* leaps to mind). So it was easy to ignore.  Fully confirmed as nuclear'd Earth later still I think, unless you paid close attention to maps apparently.

Comment: @Radhi: Ah. It has been decades since I read the series and, as a child, it probably slipped past me.

Comment: [Is the world of Shannara set in our future?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95460/is-the-world-of-shannara-set-in-our-future)

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Right.  Thought I said that.  I just looked up Allanon's History Lessons in the first book actually, and it is generic - civ of science, Great War, mutant survivors (plus Elves), nothing specific.  *Jerle Shannara* made it heavy obvious travelling over an ocean to get to "Parkasia", and then *Genesis* makes the post-Earth explicit.  I seem to recall fans comparing maps to make the link as well, but maybe that was when Parkasia was introduced. (I guess I didn't assume Sean meant Earth either *shrug*)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although there are some differences between the series and and the books, the concept of the Four Lands being in our future isn't one of them. The books are set several thousand years in the future, but I suspect the series isnt quite that far ahead in the future, which would explain why some buildings are still recognisable.

I believe the first mention of Shannara being set in the future was in the [Druid of Shannara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Druid_of_Shannara), part of the heritage of Shannara series of books. Notably the Eldwist is an ancient city turned to stone, whose buildings are described very much like our skyscapers (this was how I remember it, please someone correct me if I am wrong).

However in his books Terry Brooks has established an [entire timeline](http://www.alitheia.org/shannarafiles/Shannara_Timeline.php) extending from the late 20th century into the future history of the Shannara series of books.

Have a look at the Word and the Void series and the Genesis of Shannara series to see how our modern age turns into the world you see in the Shannara Chronicles.